# Doesn't load the data on events in fullcalender.js using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, dom-events

index.cfm

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>FullCalander Demo</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ajax call page. It  returned the JSON below

```json
[ 
    {title: 'Test event',start: '2015-02-22',
    end: '2015-02-25',color:'##00ffb8',description:"<span style='color:##00ffb8;font:bold 9pt arial'>Test event(4 days from 22-25 Feb 2015) </span> <br> 22 February 2015 <br> MS,India <br><span><a href='?eManageraction=public:main.details&event_id=1'>More Details</a></span> | <span><a href='/plugins/eManager/?testaction=public:main.iCalExport&event_id=1'><img src='/plugins/eManager/includes/assets/css/images/calendar_butt_icon.gif'></a></span> <br> <span style='color:##888989'>organized by test</span>"}
, 
    {title: 'Test 2',start: '2015-02-21',
    end: '2015-02-21',color:'##00ffb8',description:"<span style='color:##00ffb8;font:bold 9pt arial'>Test 2 </span> <br> 21 February 2015 <br> MS,India <br><span><a href='?eManageraction=public:main.details&event_id=2'>More Details</a></span> | <span><a href='/plugins/eManager/?testaction=public:main.iCalExport&event_id=2'><img src='/plugins/eManager/includes/assets/css/images/calendar_butt_icon.gif'></a></span> <br> <span style='color:##888989'>organized by test</span>"}
]
```

When I have run above code I got calendar view but didn't load event on calendar view. And ajax call return the correct JSON data. I will also try like replace the URL to above JSON data its load the events on calendar view. What is  wrong here? Please anyone help me. I am using Fullcalense version 1.6.4

Comment: Removed CF tag, as the question is about javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with your `start` and `end`. You need to check the [Event Object documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/).

Basically, you need to define the time within `start` and `end`, something like:

```
start: '2015-02-22T00:00:00',
end: '2015-02-25T00:00:00'
```

Check the [**working jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/6mp448gn/1/).

Side note: All the colors in `description` are invalid in the objects you've used. You have two `#` (eg: *color:##00ffb8*).